# How to Use IN Clause as well as AND clause in SQL together

Tags: mysql, sql, clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Events` 
WHERE `UserID` IN (SELECT `BeingFollowed` FROM `Followers` WHERE `Follower` = us)
```

Ok so above is my query and i'm trying to get all the events made by my followers and the `us` variable is a parameter in a stored routine function which is my UserID but i'm not following myself but i want to get my events also and every event has a UserID and I wanted to get all of my followers events as well as the ones i have all within the same query

Comment: What exactly "*doesn't seem to be working*"?

Comment: better to include your sample data and expected output? Right now your question is unclear what you trying to do

Comment: Alright ill update it to make it seem more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `OR` does:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Events` 
WHERE `UserID` IN (SELECT `BeingFollowed` FROM `Followers` WHERE `Follower` = us)
OR `UserID` = us
```

You could also add yourself to the subquery, but that's probably slower:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Events` 
WHERE `UserID` IN (
  SELECT `BeingFollowed` FROM `Followers` WHERE `Follower` = us
  UNION ALL
  SELECT us
)
```

Comment: @DrewPierce: Right. So MySQL still doesn't have that CBO? I keep forgetting... In this case, it won't help though, as `Followers` models a `M:N` relationship.

Comment: @Lukas Eder Thanks buddy the UNION works best when i have additional conditional clauses  after my IN clause